# node.js options list

Tags: node.js, https

Где можно найти список опций для GET запроса?
Проверяю сайт на статус код, а там идет редирект на https, а потом на другой сайт, но location указывает, что переадресация идет на https, а вот как отловить тут же переадресацию не понятно.
В C# есть AllowAutoRedirect = true,
MaxAutomaticRedirections = 1, есть ли подобное в node.js?

Comment: Я на 146% уверен что вы используете какой-то npm-пакет. Читайте документацию к этому пакету.

Comment: да стандартный http, https, либо axios, везде есть опции, но где найти их список, я не знаю.
Искал в документациях, везде просто указано что есть такой аргумент, но что в него вписывать, я не нашел.

Comment: Эм, http/https и axios это абсолютно разные вещи. В [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) это опция `maxRedirects`. В http/https ничего такого нет потому что они вообще не умеют ходить по редиректам и это нужно делать вручную.